# ArcGIS Model - Iterate Row Selection - Multipal viewsheds

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, iterator, viewshed

I've a CSV file with 106 rows with data suitable for a viewshed.

What I want to do is run an ArcGIS model where it works through the rows and produces 106 viewsheds for me (ideally the data could also be incorporated back into the original spreadsheet).

Initially I started playing with the 'Iterate Row Selection' but this does not seem to be working. It only produces one.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is an image as to how the model is set up. The Iterator is grouping by the ODI column.

[image]

Comment: You need provide a bit more information, show us your model and how you set up the iterator. Currently all you have said is "I tried something and ain't working" not much for us to go on to help you...

Comment: Thanks @Hornbydd. I've added an image to the original post.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your model it appears you have accepted default naming. I'm guessing that one viewshed that is created is always the viewshed for the very last row in your input table?

I guessing that the model runs for a long time but creates a single output?

The reason this is happening is that you are not changing the name of the output of the Viewshed tool, it's always the same output name. When using an iterator you need to be using [inline substitution](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/examples-of-inline-model-variable-substitution.htm) to create that unique output name. You do that by referencing the value in what is being called Value from your iterator.

In your case lets says output is going into c:\temp then the output parameter of your viewshed tool would be:

c:\temp\some_raster_name_%Value%.tif

%value% will be substituted with the grouping value OID. So if you have 100 unique OID values you should get 100 rasters.